# SQL Adding a column to a table, receiving duplicates

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add a column to a table, but I get duplicates which I try to avoid.
Bad description, but I hope my example will help you to understand.

(If someone can shortly explain how I create a nice table below it would help too :) )

Example:

- Table A (id, Fund) (based on data from today)
- Table B (id, Fund2) (based on data from a year ago)

Table A:

```
id   Fund
---------
1    UBS
1    UBS2
2    MS
```

Table B:

```
id   Fund2
----------
1    MS
1    UBS3
2    MS
```

Query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Fund2
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
```

Returns:

```
id   Fund    Fund2
------------------
1    UBS     MS
1    UBS     UBS3
1    UBS2    MS
1    UBS2    UBS3
2    MS      MS
```

But what I really want to get is:

```
id   Fund   Fund2
-----------------
1    UBS    MS
1    UBS2   UBS3
2    MS     MS
```

Comment: You need another key or column to narrow down the pairing of rows between the two tables. I'm supposing you don't want to do it strictly by order in which they query, or do you? In which case, you need to specify what the query order should be in order to match/line them up.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you table. There is nothing to state that '1 UBS' from A is to match with MS from B. This would work fine if table A and B had unique ids but you can't use the id 1 twice without the result you are getting. I would try to straighten out your id first.

Answer (score 0):

First, make your ids unique.  Your tables should be something like

Table A:

id   Fund

1   UBS

2   UBS2

3   MS

Table B:

id Fund2

1   MS

2   UBS3

3   MS

Then, when you do

```
SELECT A.*, B.Fund2
FROM A left join B on B.id=A.id
```

the first row of table A will match up with the first row of table B, the second rows will match up, and the third rows will match up.